# jQuery.remove() not working as expected (?)

Tags: jquery

Having read the documentation for the remove-function at http://api.jquery.com/remove/, was under the impression that the following code would work.

If I have an input element like this:

```
<input id="hiddenRatings" name="languageRatings" type="hidden" value="{5, 3, 2, , , {5, 3, 4, , , {5, 3, 2}}}"/>
```

I thought I would be able to remove it simply by doing

```
$().ready(function() {
   $('#hiddenRatings').remove();
});
```

But nothing happens, my input element remains. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Crap...... It does work! I´m using Chrome tools, and I was looking at the DOM in the Scripts tab rather than the Elements tab. The Scripts tab doesn´t update when the DOM is changed apparently...

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/9EsSg/, which is strange to be honest. `$()` should return an empty set. More information can be found in the [`jQuery()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/). Just pass the callback function to `$()` instead, that might work.

Comment: Regarding my first comment, it is not strange after all. `ready` always adds the callback to the `readyList`, no matter which elements are selected. [See the source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/src/core.js#L253). It's still more common though to use `$(document).ready(...)` or  `$(...)`.

Comment: The real strange thing is jQuery requiring an instantiated object to add `DOMContentLoaded` callback in the first place

Comment: do you have duplicate elements with that ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you are meaning to use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hiddenRatings').remove();
});
```

Using $(document) waits for all the HTML elements to be loaded into the DOM. I'm not sure if $() actually does anything: Your function will be executed before that element is loaded into the DOM (or maybe not even executed at all, since I'm not sure whether "$()" actually works).

Hope that helps

Comment: From the docs: *"As of jQuery 1.4, calling the `jQuery()` method with no arguments returns an empty jQuery set (with a `.length` property of 0). In previous versions of jQuery, this would return a set containing the `document` node."*, but surprisingly it still seems to work in 1.7, see my comment.

Comment: Weird... I haven´t thought of if, but I actually have $().ready(function() everywhere, and all the code works (some 100 lines of JS). Except for this then.

Comment: @Daniel: See my second comment to your question. If this does not work, your problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you should do `$(document).ready(`...

And it works for me [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/hbFR4/) here